# NGINX proxy_pass with html hard links

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to run a web app listening on a different port of the same server.
I'm using NGINX in order to proxy requests. I will show you an example to clarify.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.org;
...
  location /app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/public/foo;
  }
...
}
...
server {
  server_name sub.example.org;
...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
...
}
```

When I go to `http://example.org/app` I can see the redirect is correct because I see the same html I can found at `http://sub.example.org/public/foo`, but the app at `http://sub.example.org/public/foo/index.html` includes some hard linked scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/library.js"></script>
```

The console logs says that `http://example.org/static/library.js` can't be found, but this is obvious!

How can I modify the configuration in order to have `index.html` searching for `http://sub.example.org/static/library.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your upstream application's root URL to `sub.example.org`. Then the application generates correct URLs to resources it loads.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: You need to look at your application's documentation. You have given no information about your application, so I cannot help.

Comment: Except the folder `/public/foo`, the application only uses the folder `/static` and its subfolders.